# How to create a batch file to repair and start corrupted mongoDB in windows?

Tags: mongodb, batch-file, mongodb-.net-driver

I am unable to start my mongoDB after an unclean system shutdown. There is a mongod.lock with a size of 1 KB. I want to delete this file and then repair the mongoDB. I deleted the file and tried the command

> mongod --dbpath "%ProgramData%\mongodb\data\db" --repair

But I am getting an error message...

> I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 72 Requested
>   option conflicts with current storage engine option for
>   directoryPerDB; you requested false but the current server storage is
>   already set to true and cannot be changed, terminating.....

Please assist...

Comment: I think you used --directoryperDB. Try adding that to your command `mongod --dbpath "%ProgramData%\mongodb\data\db" --directoryPerDB --repair`

Comment: Adding --directoryperDB worked.. Thanks Krishna

Comment: How to run the above command "mongod --dbpath "%ProgramData%\mongodb\data\db" --repair" from a folder other than the mongodb installation folder.. When I tried "start "C:\Program Files\mongodb\mongod.exe" --dbpath "%ProgramData%\Schneider Electric\SchneiderTools\data\db" --directoryperdb --repair" ... I get a message "windows cannot find--dbpath"

Comment: Path sould not contain spaces, check `Schneider Electric` in above mentioned path

Comment: It's now `--directoryperdb` (all lowercase)

Answer (score 1):

Try to add `--directoryperDB` like this:

```
mongod --dbpath "%ProgramData%\mongodb\data\db" --directoryPerDB
```

Comment: It's now `--directoryperdb` (all lowercase)